# Chart.js Alternate value for yAxis

Tags: chart.js, axis-labels

I want to show the data which is in the following format with the basic chart.

```
yAxis=1days, 2 hours and 46 minutes
xAxis=Apple

yAxis=2 days, 2 hours and 16 minutes
xAxis=Orange
```

I was thinking to convert each of the days, hours and minutes to seconds, then I could add the seconds to the data field, and it works. (E.g. there is x number of seconds in the 2 days, 2 hours and 16 minutes)

But I want the long-form "x days,x hours and x minutes" to be shown in the yAxis and in the tooltip as well.

I appreciate if you can give me any hints.

**EDITED:**

Example chart can be viewed from the following link. This is what I currently have.

http://jsfiddle.net/wqmrL3s4/
[image]

**Question:**

What exactly I want to do is to show yAxis and tooltip in the following format:

[image]

Comment: Add an example of your data (And what is your current state? Any codepen of code snippet) + Also a screenshot of the result you want could be helpful (Copy paste the image). For now, the Q is little general + to broad (custom tooltips, custom axis, convert values to seconds). The idea of StackOverflow is to give you answers for specific Q (This is not a freelancer job board).

Comment: @EzraSiton done updated the question with sufficient info